# Make emacs do C-x h C-M-\ every time I push enter

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do I make emacs do C-x h C-M-\ every time I push enter? It annoys me that emacs doesn't auto-indent.

Comment: Here is a link to a related Emacs wiki page:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/AutoIndentation

Comment: Do you really want to reindent the *entire buffer* every single time you hit enter? Changing formatting of lines you haven't modified is overkill IMO, and it will result in commits that mix formatting changes and semantic changes. Does `C-j` instead of `Enter` do what you want? If so, rebind `Enter` to `newline-and-indent`. (You may also be interested to know that Emacs 24.4 [enables auto-indent by default](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/01/19/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-auto-indentation-by-default/)).

Comment: Ya, that's what I really want. Could you please tell me where I can get the code to paste in my .emacs?

Comment: @RenéG, did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're *really* sure this is what you want, something like this should work:

```
(defun my-newline-and-reindent-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (newline)
  (save-excursion
    (mark-whole-buffer)
    (indent-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
  (indent-for-tab-command))

(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'my-newline-and-reindent-buffer)
```

I still think this is overkill:

- You'll end up modifying the formatting of code that you aren't deliberately changing, resulting in commits that contain both semantic and stylistic changes.
- You'll almost certainly have performance issues on larger buffers.
- Most of the time (basically, every time after the first time) this will have the same effect `newline-and-indent`, but it's much less efficient.
- Some major modes might not work nicely with it. I'm thinking in particular of Python code, where Emacs doesn't necessarily know what the code's indentation level should be. Other modes have somewhat flaky indentation support.

Comment: Ya, you're right... What's the code to bind REY to C-j?

Comment: @RenéG, as mentioned in the Emacswiki page that lawlist linked there are several ways to do that. If you want to do it more or less globally, try `(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)`.